# Pass array of object in form data in swagger (cake-php)

Tags: swagger, cakephp-3.0

I have multipart/form-data request as I want to upload a file.Now I want to send data with file and I am using form-data.One of the field is array of object, So now how can I pass array of object in formData in swagger UI with cakephp.

Answer (score 0):

Vishal, you can use serialize() for this and pass the serialize variable on the form element, its behave like string and after it you can use unserialize().

$string_var = serialize(Array);

$Array = unserialize(string_var);